# List.contains() not returning correct result, but manual search does

Tags: java

I have a strange issue happening with my code below:

```
  RestAPIHeader requestedBy = new RestAPIHeader("X-Requested-By", "test");

  // Act
  RestAPIRequest req = prepareLoginRequest(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

  // The following returns a list of header objects such that one of them
  // is "X-Requested-By: test"
  List<RestAPIHeader> headers = req.getAllHeaders();

  boolean foundRequestedBy = false;
  for (RestAPIHeader h : headers) {
      Log.d(LOGTAG, "Header: " + h.toString());
      if (requestedBy.equals(h)) {
          foundRequestedBy = true;
      }
  }

  // Assert
  assertNotNull(req);

  // This assertion passes
  assertTrue(foundRequestedBy);

  // This assertion fails
  assertTrue(headers.contains(requestedBy));
```

What bothers me is that it seems like `headers.contains(requestedBy)` should be equivalent to `foundRequestedBy` in this code (since this is the result of a simple search). However, as I mention in the comments, it doesn't actually return the same value. It almost seems as though `contains` isn't using `equals()`, but rather `==`. Can someone point out why this is the case?

**Edit**:

The `equals` method of the `RestAPIHeader` class is as follows:

```
  public boolean equals(RestAPIHeader aOther) {
    return mPropertyName.equals(aOther.getHeaderName())
      && mPropertyValue.equals(aOther.getHeaderValue());
  }
```

Comment: What's the concrete type of `headers`?  Is it a `List` from the core Java API, or something custom?

Comment: It's a `List` from the core Java API. Actually, what is returned is an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I don't see you adding `requestBy` to the `headers`. How is the `equals` method of `RestAPIHeader` implemented?

Comment: The `contains` method should use the `equals` method which won't work unless you overwrite it (the default _is_ to use `==`)--however, you use the `equals` method so it should be properly overwritten.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I gave the implementation of `equals` above. Adding "X-Requested-By" to the headers is done inside of `prepareLoginRequest`, and really isn't all that relevant, since if it's not in the list, then both of the methods of determining if it's in the list should return `false`.

Comment: @Jared I did implement it. I gave the implementation in an edit to the original question.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure this is relevant, but the code is running against the Dalvik VM (i.e. it's Android code).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The signature of equals is

```
public boolean equals(Object o);
```

So your equals method

```
public boolean equals(RestAPIHeader aOther);
```

is an overload, not an override. This overload will not be called by the contains routine. So you just need to correct the signature to

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof RestAPIHeader))
        return false;

    RestAPIHeader aOther = (RestAPIHeader)o;

    /* same as yours from here */
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you. I knew it was something minor that I totally missed. *facepalm*

Comment: use `@Override` to avoid such case

Comment: Indeed, using the `@Override` annotation will generate a compilation error when this happens. There is really no reason not to use it.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't in this case because I stupidly also put `equals(RestAPIHeader)` in the interface. (`@Override` is in the code, but I neglected to copy-paste it). It's like a comedy of errors here...

Comment: @jwir3 That is funny. : )

Answer (score 2):

Correct way of implementing equals is:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object aOther) {...
```

And not `public boolean equals(RestAPIHeader aOther)`